# Getting a specific part of a URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a couple of URL's that I need to obtain a specific part of the last part of the URI

If I have the url `www.test.co/index.php/government-printer-sales.html` I only need to obtain `government` from the URL. All url's are in the same structure so if I have `www.test.co/index.php/management-fees.html` I need to obtain the word `management`

I tried the following

```
var str = document.URL.split('/');
 var type = str[5].split('-',1);
```

which gives me some result, but I'm sure there is a better way. If there's anyway I can obtain this from eiter mootools or just plain javascript

Comment: Is that the real URL? If there are only 2 slashes, then why do you access index `5` of the splitted string?

Comment: @pimvdb - just example, there can be more that two dashes

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression to pull out the string after the last slash and before the first dash:

```
var regex = /\/([^/\-]+)[^/]*$/;
var matches = regex.exec('www.test.co/index.php/government-printer-sales.html');
var type = matches[1];  // government
```

Answer (score 3):

You can look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) and then check this code:

```
var myString = "www.test.co/index.php/government-printer-sales.html";
var myRegexp = /(www.test.co\/index.php\/)(\w+)-(.)*/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match);
```

Answer (score 3):

Splice is a great function passing in a negative number as the first argument will create a new array with elements counting from the end of the array.

```
document.URL
> "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671441/getting-a-specific-part-of-a-url-using-javascript"

document.URL.split('/').splice(-1)[0].split('-')[0]
> "getting"
```

This is similar to python's list splicing lst[:-1]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var type = window.location.pathname.match(/index.php\/([^-]+)(?:-)/)[1];
```

It searches for any characters following `index.php/` excluding a hyphen, but followed by a single hyphen and fetches the value in between.